# How to sort Youtube API

Tags: python, api, youtube

I have created a function to pull youtube's video data and load it into a data frame. I need to reverse the order so that I can append new videos to the end of the EXCEL as I'm not aware of code to append lines by adding a new row to the top. My code:

```
def get_video_details(youtube, video_ids):
    all_data = []
    for i in range(0, len(video_ids), 50):
        request = youtube.videos().list(
            part = 'snippet, statistics' , 
            id = ','.join(video_ids[i: i + 50]) ,
            #order = 'date'
        )
        response = request.execute()

        for video in response['items']:
            video_stats = dict(
                result_video_name = video['snippet']['title']  ,
                result_video_id = video['id'] ,                
                result_video_description = video['snippet']['description']  ,
                result_video_upload_time = video['snippet']['publishedAt']  ,
                result_video_views = video['statistics']['viewCount'] ,  
                result_video_likes = video['statistics']['likeCount'] ,  
                result_video_favorites = video['statistics']['favoriteCount'] ,  
                result_video_comments = video['statistics']['commentCount']  
                )
            all_data.append(video_stats)

    return all_data
```

I tried the order = 'date' option per YouTube's recommendation, but it's giving me a type error:
TypeError: Got an unexpected keyword argument order

I followed a similar question ([YouTube API: youtube.search().list won't order by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073029/youtube-api-youtube-search-list-wont-order-by-date) and [Sorting Youtube API result from playlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22893328/sorting-youtube-api-result-from-playlist)) and it appears it's still not working or not really a feature. Is this still the case or has anyone found a work around?

If I put everything into a data frame, I get an output like this:

2921 - 2016-02-02T02:11:11Z

0    - 2022-12-12T21:10:11Z

I would like 0 to be the first video uploaded in 2016, and 2921 to the 0, uploaded today. I can use my data frame to flip them around, but the unique ID will not be changed.

Comment: `order` isn't a parameter from [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint.

Comment: the question is missing parts of code such as the imports...  please add them so that there is sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example